# android 4.1.0 phonegap app images disappear on reboot

Tags: image, cordova, android-camera

I have an app we use internally, it has been working well for around a month, until yesterday. on a droid razr max using 4.1.0 os the app lost all images when the battery died. I am saving the images to the scard and taking the location the camera sends back and saving that to the sqlite database. the location appears to still be in the database, the images are still on the sdcard but are not displaying on the app. I do not have access to that phone to check the database to see the saved image location but noticed that on ios the camera returned a temp image location. Is this the case on the droid 4.1.0? if not any ideas?